# Run Virtualbox at boot without a Desktop Enviroment

Tags: 12.04, boot, virtualbox

I am wondering if there is a way to run virtualbox XP machine on a Ubuntu base system with no/very minimal Ubuntu Desktop Environment.

I want to use Ubuntu for as the base operation system for such things as Samba, DNS, LAMP. But some of the the applications we have developed and use are windows only. And require a bit more "juice" than Ubuntu But we also need the Windows GUI to make changes, etc.

I would like this on one machine, rather than a two.

Comment: I never did it, but it is possible: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#vboxheadless

Comment: Looks like a good guide, but I am looking to be able to use the XP machine on the Server via screen that is plugged in and not view an RDP. I understand this may be a weird request.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean without desktop environment of the operating system on which virtualbox is installed, it doesn't seem likely to me (virtualbox is a program and hence needs the majority of an operating system loaded to work)

Also, why would this be required, could you not just then install the operating system you are sandboxing on a separate partition (and it would probably work better than from inside virtualbox?). At least as far as I can see, the main advantage of running virtualbox is to be able to simultaneously use two operating systems. If you have minimal desktop environment then surely you lose a lot of functionality for that OS.

However, if you mean you want the sandboxed system to be minimal (for example, just command line interface) then this is much more feasible

Comment: I am looking to run Ubuntu server but also an XP machine running on it for other tasks. XP would need most of the system resources (there inst much available) to run as stable as possible. I would need to be able to use windows. Is there a good guide on how it work and even how to set it up sandboxing?

Comment: Okay, if you fully explain your purpose in the original question by editing it, it may help with better answers. Just to clarify, are you wanting to run Ubuntu Server as the base operating system, and then Windows XP in a virtualbox within Ubuntu Server? It would seem easier and more efficient in my opinion to install virtualbox on XP to run Ubuntu Server if you want the performance from XP

Comment: Yes, I want to use Ubuntu for as the base operation system for such things as Samba, DNS, LAMP. But some of the the applications we have developed and use are windows only. And require a bit more "juice" than Ubuntu But we also need the Windows GUI to make changes, etc. I would like this on one machine, rather than a two. I'm kind of new to Ubuntu (only a few months experience)